# fgetcsv is not parsing the line properly

Tags: php, sql-server, parsing, csv, fgetcsv

This is the first line of my CSV (answer.csv):

```
Respondent Name,name,1
```

I am using the following code to parse and insert it into a db

```
if (($handle = fopen("answer.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    echo $num;
    echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
    $row++;

    $query_add="INSERT INTO  answer (`AnswerValue`,`AnswerKey` ,`Question`)
    VALUES ($data[0],$data[1],$data[2])";
    echo $query_add;
    echo mysql_query($query_add) or die(mysql_error());
    #for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
    #    echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
    #}
  }
  fclose($handle);
  }
```

However, I get the following error because the line is not being parsed by ",":

### Ouput :

```
1 fields in line 1: 

Respondent Name name    1

    INSERT INTO answer (`AnswerValue`,`AnswerKey` ,`Question`) 
       VALUES (Respondent Name  name    1,,)

You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
syntax to use near 'Name    name 1,,)' at line 2
```

For some reason, it shows there is only one field in line 1 whereas there are 3 fields if we look at the csv file...

Anyone knows why?

Comment: To avoid problems later, in case your data contains [something unexpected](http://xkcd.com/327/), please read [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and follow the advice given in the answers.

Comment: Learn to use MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements, and bind variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must put the values in the quotes.

try this :

```
$query_add="INSERT INTO  answer (`AnswerValue`,`AnswerKey` ,`Question`)
    VALUES ('".$data[0]."','".$data[1]."','".$data[2]."')";
```

and when I try your code, with my changes above,this is the result :

```
3

3 fields in line :
INSERT INTO answer (`AnswerValue`,`AnswerKey` ,`Question`) 
VALUES ('Respondent Name','name','1')
```

Comment: doesn't work: I get the following:
INSERT INTO answer (`AnswerValue`,`AnswerKey` ,`Question`) VALUES ('Respondent Name name 1','','')11

Comment: as you can see, the entire row is getting inserted in column 1

Comment: try creating the file again, maybe its corrupted . I dont know.
 your code is all right.

Comment: you're right..i  uploaded to file via ftp on my server and it wasn't being read properly. It works fine when I run it on a local file on my computer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your CSV file charset is invalid. Make sure it is encoded in UTF8.

Comment: im actually importing the file